# DBCP and Hibernate on Spring, doesn't re-open dead connections, why?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm using Hibernate and DBCP to manage mySQL connections, all in a Spring project.

Everything is working fine. The only problem is that if the app stays still for a long time, it will throw a an exception because the connection is dead (same thing if I restart mySQLd when the application is up). It's not big deal because the user will get the exception page (or the custom one) and a reload will solve the problem. But I'd like to solve it. Here is part of the exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:
```

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.io.EOFException
MESSAGE: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

I googled around and I found that with mysql I should set the `dbcp.BasicDataSource` property `testOnBorrow` to `true`, which I've done in my servlet-context.xml:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${mySQL.host}/${mySQL.db}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mySQL.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mySQL.pass}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

But the problem persists. Any clues?

Solution! I used:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${mySQL.host}/${mySQL.db}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mySQL.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mySQL.pass}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"></property>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you set `testOnBorrow` you must also set `validationQuery` -

> validationQuery - The SQL query that will be used to
>   validate connections from this pool
>   before returning them to the caller.
>   If specified, this query MUST be an
>   SQL SELECT statement that returns at
>   least one row.

I have also set `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` so the dead connections will be evicted from the pool.

Comment: Does this mean that this query will run every time Hibernate borrows one connection from DBCP??? Isn't this too heavy?

Comment: It should be a tiny query that runs very fast. Assuming Hibernate runs several not tiny queries for each connection, one more tiny query should not effect performance.

Comment: hm.... Yeah I see, I used SELECT 1 (it's suggested on the dbcp wiki). Anyway, I think that hibernate will get a connection everytime it opens a session. This means roughly everytime the controller processes a request. I hope this is just a mySQL related issue.